# How to prevent Oracle archived redo log from filling up database server disk?

Tags: oracle, rman

My database server's disk is getting full really quickly with archive files.
The size of the database is around 60Gb and I have about 30 Gb of free disk.

Problem is, the 30Gb get used by archived log in about a week even though my retention policy is set to REDUNDANCY 1.

```
RMAN> show all;

using target database control file instead of recovery catalog
RMAN configuration parameters for database with db_unique_name MYDB are:
CONFIGURE RETENTION POLICY TO REDUNDANCY 1; # default
CONFIGURE BACKUP OPTIMIZATION OFF; # default
CONFIGURE DEFAULT DEVICE TYPE TO 'SBT_TAPE';
CONFIGURE CONTROLFILE AUTOBACKUP OFF; # default
CONFIGURE CONTROLFILE AUTOBACKUP FORMAT FOR DEVICE TYPE SBT_TAPE TO '%F'; # default
CONFIGURE CONTROLFILE AUTOBACKUP FORMAT FOR DEVICE TYPE DISK TO '%F'; # default
CONFIGURE DEVICE TYPE SBT_TAPE PARALLELISM 1 BACKUP TYPE TO BACKUPSET; # default
CONFIGURE DEVICE TYPE DISK PARALLELISM 1 BACKUP TYPE TO BACKUPSET; # default
CONFIGURE DATAFILE BACKUP COPIES FOR DEVICE TYPE SBT_TAPE TO 1; # default
CONFIGURE DATAFILE BACKUP COPIES FOR DEVICE TYPE DISK TO 1; # default
CONFIGURE ARCHIVELOG BACKUP COPIES FOR DEVICE TYPE SBT_TAPE TO 1; # default
CONFIGURE ARCHIVELOG BACKUP COPIES FOR DEVICE TYPE DISK TO 1; # default
CONFIGURE CHANNEL DEVICE TYPE 'SBT_TAPE' PARMS  'SBT_LIBRARY=/u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/db_1/lib/libosbws11.so,   SBT_PARMS=(OSB_WS_PFILE=/u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/db_1/dbs/osbswsMYDB.ora)';
CONFIGURE MAXSETSIZE TO UNLIMITED; # default
CONFIGURE ENCRYPTION FOR DATABASE OFF; # default
CONFIGURE ENCRYPTION ALGORITHM 'AES128'; # default
CONFIGURE COMPRESSION ALGORITHM 'BASIC' AS OF RELEASE 'DEFAULT' OPTIMIZE FOR LOAD TRUE ; # default
CONFIGURE ARCHIVELOG DELETION POLICY TO BACKED UP 1 TIMES TO 'TAPE';
CONFIGURE SNAPSHOT CONTROLFILE NAME TO '/u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/db_1/dbs/snapcf_MYDB.f'; # default
```

So, if the flash recovery area is not cleared every week, the database server would run out of space and error ORA-00257 would be prompted.

```
ERROR: ORA-00257: archiver error. Connect internal only, until freed.
```

Any ideas on how to resolve this issue?

Comment: do you make regularly backups of the archive and of the data files? Are this backups to tape (this is your default backup type). What is your backup schedule?

Answer (score 0):

I wonder whether you understand the relation ship between "retention policy" of RMAN with the "action" of cleaning FRA?
Your current RETENTION POLICY is 1 means all backup (incre level 0, level 1, archive log, …) don't necessary will be marked OBSOLETE but Not deleted (they still consume storage space). OBSOLETE means they can safely but deleted but still satify your retention policy.
Solution in this case is to schedule crontab or job to automatically delete obsolete backup (rman> delete noprompt obsolete;) after each rman incre level 0 backup.
In case of deleting obsolete backup and still facing space pressure - then you have to request System Admin to increase your current FRA location (increase db_recovery_file_dest_size) or choose another location for db_recovery_file_dest init parameter.

Answer (score -2):

your options are,

1. Increase the disk space
2. Find out the reason for huge archivelog generation.
3. Schedule archivelog backups twice per day to backup and clear the space.

Comment: why should he increase the disk space? Why do you think that the sie of archive log is huge?

Comment: first of all apologies for the late response. As he mentioned that both db files and archivelogs on same location, increasing the disk space further would be an instant resolution option for them. i also agree that, archivelog doesnt need to be accumulated/stored after it is been backup.